# How to ng-repeat and bind $scope items to model when $scope items are stored in an object

Tags: angularjs

I currently have my `$scope` items stored in this object:

```
$scope.columnList = {
    "date": $scope.newDate, 
    "time": $scope.newTime, 
    "exercise": $scope.newExercise,
    "reps": $scope.newReps,
    "weight": $scope.newWeight, 
    "location": $scope.newLocation
};
```

I store them in an object because it means I can build a table using `ng-repeat`

I'm having trouble building a table of inputs using this object. I don't think the `$scope` item is binding properly in this `ng-repeat` because `ng-model` is not evaluating to the `$scope` item.

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, value) in columnList"><input type="text" ng-model="value"></td>
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZ8AqJJlUMxQOxoitEsh?p=preview)

**Is there a way to do this?**

The keys evaluate properly, but they are strings:

```
<th ng-repeat="(key, value) in columnList">{{key}}</th>
```

Comment: you're plunker is throwing an exception `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys`

Comment: try this: `<tr ng-repeat="set in workoutData track by $index">` to at least remove the duplicate exception.

Comment: Well I can believe I didn't see that Error, but my original problem remains